# Auto expiration and deletion of znodes in Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Is there a way to have a znode auto expire and delete (under Zookeeper control) after some length of time? I don't need to keep a znode around after that point. I want to conserve resources.

If your answer is "no, your application has to handle that", would you kindly point me to some documentation that makes that clear? (Right now, I suspect this may be the case, but I don't want to assume it too quickly.)

If the answer is "not currently, but Zookeeper could be extended to do that", then I would be especially thankful to a suggestion of a good starting point for making such an enhancement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Patrick on [The Zookeeper Mailing List: ZNODE time to live](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/zookeeper-user/201204.mbox/%3CCANLc_9KUL441ZYnArwx4RRyki8msFhTHbs__sEzBZjvHPYA9sw@mail.gmail.com%3E):

> There is no TTL like feature in the current implementation.

That was 26 Apr 2012, which would correspond to version 3.3.5 according to the list of [Apache ZooKeeper Releases](http://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html).

I skimmed the release notes for [3.3.6](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.6/releasenotes.html), [3.4.4](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.4/releasenotes.html), and [3.4.5](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/releasenotes.html) and found no mention of "TTL" or "time to live" or anything along those lines.

Comment: [ZOOKEEPER-1925](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1925) requested a TTL feature in May 2014. It has not been updated since. The consensus of comments seemed to be that a TTL feature should be implemented at the application layer, not in ZK.

Answer (score 3):

Zookeeper 3.5.3 contains support for ttl on zknodes.

A [new function call](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.3-beta/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#create(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20java.util.List,%20org.apache.zookeeper.CreateMode,%20org.apache.zookeeper.data.Stat,%20long)) is added where you can provide a ttl for a node in milliseconds.